# How to get rid of an empty panel in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying out Visual Studio Code.  Yesterday, I opened a file outside of the git directory I was working in.  I eventually moved and renamed the file and somewhere along the line, I ended up with the empty panel shown in the attached screenshot.  I tried clicking every GUI element and every menu item and I could not get rid of it.  I could close that file and it would go away, but once I re-opened it, it would come back, so it seemed to be associated specifically with that file.

I could split the view and add more tabs, but there was no way to get rid of it.  I selected `view > editor layout > single` many times and it would not go away.  All I could do was make it smaller by dragging the vertical divider.

This morning, I closed it and re-opened it, and it was gone.  Unfortunately, despite trying to reproduce the steps that lead to that empty panel, I could not make that panel show up again.

Does anyone know what that panel was, why it was appearing with that file, and how to make it go away if it happens again?

[image: Unknown Recalcitrant Panel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file basically shows you all the edits you've made since you last saved the file in git. By clicking on the source control button on the activity bar on the left side you can view your changes on the files you're working on. You can't actually edit it, it just shows the changes you've made.

To actually open the file and edit it you can either go back to the top left button called explorer on the activity bar or click on the little file button next to the name of the file (next to the + sign and the arrow).

Checkout [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKNYgP0yEOY) video by vscode which explains it

Comment: Ooooohhhhh. Wait, so you're saying that I unwittingly opened a file displayed in source control? I totally just reproduced that. I could not tell it wasn't the file I'd been editing all along! Nor did I know how to google my scenario to figure out what was happening. That's so much! Mystery solved!

Comment: Is that little orange "DictReader" icon meant to identify the type of tab as a source control tab?

Comment: In the breadcrumbs at the top of the file? I dont't think so. That's something in the file (for example a header, function, etc.) which is currently selected.

Comment: Are there any visual cues to distinguish a source control tab from a regular file tab?

Comment: [This](https://dev.to/vscode/vscode-breadcrumbs-are-here-jkn) might explain that.

Comment: I don't know tbh. The git panel always has the saved changes on the left and the current changes on the right and a normal tab you can edit.

Comment: @hepcat72 when there is a `(xxxx)` part in the tab title it is a Diff view, the `xxxx` tells you what is compared

Comment: I feel like I'm blind. Where is the xxxx in the screenshot?

Comment: On the tag where it says `load_compound_data.py (Untracked)`, by xxxx he meant Untracked. It can also say Modified if you've tracked the file but have modified it since.